# Is it smart for a student to list athletic roles under Experience, instead of Hobbies, category?

Tags: resume, student

Should a High School or College student list their athletic experiences, paid or not, for the school or not, under the category of Experience?

This could be a resumé or a school application.

Aren't learning experiences from sports just as meaningful as from non-sports experiences?

Comment: Related https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/131790/58537

Comment: `Should a High School or College student list their athletic experiences, paid or not, for the school or not, under the category of Experience?` - No.

Comment: Wow. Another downvote for a perfectly good question.

Comment: A team sport isn't really a work experience...unless you're an athlete or tangentially related field like sports broadcasting. I may consider work experience if you're paid athlete (it's a paid job) versus a club/school sport. A team sport is definitely an extracurricular experience that you could list on your college application.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Right. "Starting Point Guard" • Developed time and priority management skills to accommodate academic and athletic obligations. (For example.)


Time and time again I hear professional athletes speak to sports as a means to learn life skills. So why can't those be "experiences" just as any other skill learning on the job.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Point Guard is a work experience as it's done on behalf of someone else. It's employment without an exchange of cash. The Point Guard creates revenue for the school in exchange for the very experience I noted. Gardner, for yourself, isn't.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ok, what happens when they're objectively significant? How does one give credence to the endless stories of lives between changed through pursuit of athletic excellence? And why would it even matter to you? Would you give negative marks because a person claimed they experienced significant gains through sports? ... or would that prompt a reaction to meet that person because they were insightful enough to recognize their achievement and courageous enough to put it on paper?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere  I asked the question to hear reasonable examples of opposition. Your opposition is that "normal" school activities be twisted into leadership examples. That wasn't the question nor any of my examples. My examples are of learning experiences, as the question states, not exaggeration which clearly wouldn't be justified regardless of its source.  As you say "I see nothing insightful or courageous." ... Ok well then you don't. Should I say "I'm not sure why you answered the question, as it appears you have already made you your mind up anyway."

Comment: @JoeStrazzere  Yes, I've argued with every answer because none are stating a reason. And I see no answer from you.

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm speaking about. "Dr. Mae Jemison made history when she became the first woman of color to travel to space." At 1:25 she answers the question "How did being a dancer help you become an astronaut?" and her reply is 'the discipline... practice all the time... memorize... becoming thick skinned'.

She says those were critical skills. If not in the Experience area of the resume where and how should someone list those achievements?

https://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2019/06/10/mae-jemison-biography-scn-orig.cnn/video/playlists/moon-space/

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Of course it is. It's where everything is talked about. What does that have to do with the resume? (Or even perhaps cover letter instead... perhaps that's a better place.)  Why do you call the video I noted an interview? Does it have to be explained that it's just an example of how significant sports can be?  Why does the resume of Dr. Jemison have anything to do with 99.99% of everyone else's situation that isn't like, or likely as good as, hers?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, I brought her up. Then you made divergent points. I pointed out the disparity. Now you say "no matter". Another hit and run. "I tried." ... to do what?  I've no idea. Do you?

Answer (score 7):

If you are submitting the resume to Sports related fields, then yes.  If not, then no.
Save your experiences as team capt. or team work in general for the interview.

Comment: Why would it matter?  If the person can distinguish life skills learned through athletics why isn't that an experience? Does it become a good idea if the student was on a scholarship as then it would be a Professional experience?

Answer (score 3):

### No

I'm of the opinion that the "Experience" section of a resume should be reserved for employment history. I might be OK with something else being included here but I would need a very compelling reason for doing so and I've yet to come across one.

Most of the time, extra-curricular activities will go in their own section. Even if the activity is directly related to the type of job I'm applying for, I would still put it here to keep it separate from my employment history.

If you don't have much (or any) employment history, I'd say don't worry about it. High school/college graduates aren't really expected to have any relevant job experience anyway, which is pretty much the same as having no experience at all. Employers know this and accept it.

If you've never had any jobs before, you can still include the Experience section and just have a short sentence or two explaining why you've never pursued employment (chose to focus on studies, etc) so that it's there (prospective employers will look for it) and not just empty white space. Then feel free to pad up the other sections with all the cool stuff you've done.

Comment: It is employment. It's a barter. Point Guard is a work experience as it's done on behalf of someone else. The Point Guard creates revenue for the school in exchange for the very experience I noted. Working for yourself isn't employment so, as someone said above,  Gardner, for yourself, isn't a list-worthy experience.

Is managing the creation of 50 cakes for a PTA meeting experience? Absolutely. 

How about volunteering?

Comment: @RandyZeitman Those are all things that absolutely should go on a resume but unless you're getting paid to do them, I believe they belong in a different section. The "Experience" section should be reserved for employment history (and probably also renamed to something more reflective of that, such as "Employment History").

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the dissenting opinion.

**Yes, athletic roles are fine to list on a resume for someone in HS/College - *As long as that job in some way demonstrates a quality that a hiring manager would think important*.**

For instance, if I was looking to hire a Junior Dev, and got an application from a recent grad that said:

> **Athletic Experiences:** Captain of HS Floobyball Team, Assistant Captain
>   of College Floobyball Team

... it would tell me: this person is someone that:

- Likely gets along with others reasonably well
- Likely can function in a leadership role

I mean, yeah, it's not as impressive as if you were the leader of your college's [RelevantAcademicClub], but to say that it wouldn't matter at *all* is a bit much.

Again, this isn't to simply say, "List any athletic experience you have".  It has to demonstrate a quality that would be important to the hiring manager.  But if your experience does that (regardless of what that experience is) you should list it.  It's why I would *always* recommend to list military service - because being able to work well with others, follow directives, etc is always a useful skill set.

Comment: Finally a voice of reason. I don't know what the others were thinking. This is for a high school or a college student. Obviously, it's very different for those guys/gals.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk  Why is so hard to understand? (And I don't have a single positive vote on this.) 

If I sell tennis lessons, by myself and for myself, it's professional experience but if I volunteer those same lessons for an organization it's not? 

e.g. "Starting Point Guard • Transformed from lazy and directionless individual to focused and goal-oriented by developing time and priority management skills to accommodate academic and athletic obligations."

Is that a bad thing to say?

Comment: "It has to demonstrate a quality that would be important to the hiring manager."

Comment: @RandyZeitman and Kevin, plz look at aleppke's answer if you wonder what the reasoning of us others is. The question is about which category to list this under, not whether they should omit it altogether. Employment is employment, other demonstrated skills are other demonstrated skills.

Comment: @Helen That's right. That's why it belongs as experience and not employment. Do you think a volunteer who manages a team is a demonstrated skill, employment, or experience? If I sell tennis lessons, by myself and for myself, is it employment (self) or experience? ... but if I volunteer those same lessons for an organization it's a demonstrated skill? (hardly - they're all experiences).

Comment: I'm an extremely senior-level firmware engineer. Depending on the position, =I= list my volunteer activities. And I've been at this thing for almost 40 years. People aren't one-dimensional beings. As long as "volunteer activities" demonstrate interpersonal skill and leadership potential, put them on the resume! The only exception is purely religious or political activities -- big no-no for a lot of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Content-wise, they should be listed if they support some of the statements in the resume.

I.e. it tingles my nose when I read in a resume that someone presents themselves as "strong team player" and then list, among the hobbies, "tennis player" or "chess player", since in those sports there is few to null team aspect.

If they instead list sports such as "basketball", "volleyball", "cricket" or whatever team sport it can be, it is a confirmation of their statement. Even more if they had a more specific role, like captain or manager.

Whether to list them under hobbies/other or experiences, I am more inclined to prefer seeing them under hobbies/other, unless they are really professional experience.

Comment: Are they specifically relating the team player to those hobbies?

Comment: @RandyZeitman, no. But it triggers my skepticism, when a self proclaimed team player does solitary activities.

Comment: Very fair. (assuming there's no other examples of team member, such as through employment).

Comment: Playing basketball, volleyball, cricket etc. in a team doesn't mean you are a "team player".

Comment: @gnasher729, it means that at least one can pursue a common goal interacting with other humans. I have seen individuals struggling just to make a simple CAD design with 2 other students for a university assignment.

Answer (score -1):

> paid or not

If it was paid, yes.

If it was not, then definitely no.

Comment: so, if one has got one dollar for participating in their village checkers competition, they include it into their resume? Because they were paid

Comment: Winning money isn't getting paid. How about if I volunteer to tutor checker and chess to young kids to gain critical thinking skills and it turns many of them around from bad kids to college kids, etc. Is that a real job experience without being paid?

Of course it is ... why should being paid have to do with anything. You're telling me if I sell tennis lessons, by myself and for myself, it's professional experience but if I volunteer those same lessons for an organization it's not?

Comment: @RandyZeitman I understand that it can be more complicated and that probably more info is needed. But if someone has worked professionally on something, most of the time they are entitled to have it among their "experience".

Comment: @gnat I assumed that the OP means "paid" as "I received salary for my work in a professional position". See also comment above.

Comment: Unpaid work can demonstrate untapped leadership potential. It can also demonstrate a willingness to help others, which is a huge plus in a workplace. I helped teach bicycle repair to clients of a charity. Since I'm late-career and "mentoring other software engineers" is a big part of what I want to do, I listed it. Yes, I helped other people fix bicycles, didn't get paid, and I landed a very well paying job with that on my resume.